# What is the difference between Prost and Prosit?

Tags: word-usage, difference, colloquial

From what I can gather, *Prost* is the colloquial form of *Prosit*.  However, I’ve searched around quite a bit and I see all sorts of explanations.  A lot of them explain it the same way, almost word-for-word, as that found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast_(honor)) for toasts.  However, I’ve also seen responses from people who say they are native Germans and they say they’ve never even heard the word *Prosit*.

So, even if we take the single-source Wikipedia explanation as true, what are the differences in usage?  Is it simply that *Prosit* is old-fashioned and most people just say *Prost*, or is it regional (I seen some claim it is a Germany/Austria difference, and some suggest it is a Hochdeutsch/Bairisch difference)?

For what it’s worth, [John Banner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Banner), who was born in Austria and came to the United States speaking only German, says *Prosit* several times on various episodes of *[Hogan’s Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogan%27s_Heroes)*.  It is also the name of an oft-played song at Oktoberfest:

> Ein Prosit, ein Prosit  der Gemütlichkeit

Comment: Trivia: In Sweden we say ”prosit” after someone sneezes.

Comment: *Prosit* has an *i* (and therefore one syllable) more than *prost*. Thats all. They mean the same

Comment: @Fredrik This was also common in southern parts of Germany. But I haven't heard it anymore for quite some time.

Comment: A magazine named "Prosit" was distributed for decades to visitors and tourists to New Braunfels, Texas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most logical reasoning that I can follow is *Prosit* being the outdated or higher-class term. When picturing a group in a bar, all I can hear them say is *Prost,* never *Prosit.* At the same time, the Bavarian cultural song *ein Prosit* that you quote is frozen in a not-entirely modern German.

However I *can* imagine someone important in a suit standing up at a high-class dinner and calling a toast for somebody else important in a suit and doing so by saying ‘ein Prosit auf unseren Gastgeber Herrn Professor Doktor Hubermayr!’ But, he could also say *Prost* (although I would think it slightly less likely).

Comment: Agree. *Prosit* is still used in specific circumstances, and beyond that by anyone who wants to show off they know their Latin.

Answer (score 8):

Both words stem from the same source, lat. *prosit*, i.e. literally *may it be beneficial* (~ to your health).

Pros**i**t is certainly higher register, but rarely used these days, except for a few well-known collocations. *Ein Prosit der Gemütlichkeit* has been mentioned, the only other one I can think of off the top of my head is *Prosit Neujahr* (Happy New Year). If you're drinking to somebody's health, it's always *Prost*.

Comment: Even the "Happy New Year" is usually spoken "Prost Neujahr", at least in the northern parts of Germany.

Comment: Only there, I suppose. In my region (Eastern Austria) the _i_ (as in Pros**i**t) is very clearly audible.

Answer (score 1):

*Prosit* is tipicaly used during Oktoberfest and in Bavaria. Anyone ever being at an Oktoberfest will be familiar with the term. While the rest of Germany usuaully uses the term *Prost*, as well as other such as *zum Wohl, Glück aus*, etc. Similar to English where we use *cheers* and others such as “over the lips and through the gums watch out stomach here it comes” they’re all regional for the same wonderfull reason.

Comment: Prosit is neither typical for Bavaria nor the Oktoberfest. Is it possible that you mixed it up with the song [Ein Prosit der Gemütlichkeit](https://oktoberfest-guide.com/magazine/ein-prosit-der-gemuetlichkeit/)?

Answer (score 1):

Prosit was (and may still be) part of the formulaic and intricate ritual (the "Bierkomment") used in the German drinking societies to toast each others' health. You can read about this in Maurice Baring's "Puppet Show of Memory", pp. 121ff.

I have a German friend and once mentioned this ritual to him. He told me how much he hated the very idea of it, because of its association with the the German aristocracy and the Nazis.

Though Prosit may very well be used elsewhere, this association might be why it's gone out of style.

Comment: I don’t associate *Prosit* with nazis, but maybe it’s because I’m Bavarian and ‘Ein Prosit der Gemütlichkeit’ is so common here?

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: Prosit is Austrian, Prost is German.

This handy [map of the distribution of both words](https://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_8/r8_f1a_b/) shows it.

Comment: Your links only mentions a very special case, namely "happy new year", and there are lots of variations besides Pros(i)t Neujahr.

Comment: Yes, but it very clearly shows the regional distribution of both words, and some data is better than relying on personal anecdotes and no data at all ;)

Comment: I disagree, at least in this case. It shows the regional distribution between _frohes/gutes/gesundes neues (Jahr)_ and  Pros(i)t Neujahr. While the collocation "Prosit Neujahr" is more common in Austria than in some parts of Germany, this provides no insight in the case of Prost vs. Prosit used in other context.

Comment: It certainly shows that "Prosit" is extremely rare outside of Austria and Bavaria. The fact that all the answers to the contrary (and I assume the downvotes) are from people living either in Austria or Bavaria and seem convinced that everybody uses it the way they do does not mean this is the standard German usage. As someone from the Cologne area, I cannot imagine anyone ever saying "Prosit", it is completely unknown here, and as such must be a local variation.

Comment: Please don't tell me about "standard" German usage. While it is true that I speak Austrian German, I do by no means consider it non-standard or inferior in any other way. It's perfectly fine for you not to use an expression and for others, including me, to do -- German being the pluricentric language that it is.

Comment: It would never occur to me (Mecklenburg) to say *Prost Neujahr*, *Pros**i**t* would be the expected version (with *Frohes Neues* as alternative). Definitely not simply Austrian.